# When i am zooming in my page is transforming into mess

Tags: html, css, zooming

I need help. When i am zooming in my page is transforming into mess. 
I'll post my code here and screenshots of it.[Screenshot of page when it isn't zoomed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPN1G.jpg)[When it's zoomed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onjlY.jpg) Is there any possible way to fix it now?
And also when i zoom out it is breaking.

I hope that i explained that well.
And here is my code:

```css
         body {
      background: #DF7401;
      background-size: cover;
         font-family: Arial;
         color: white;
      }

     ul {
    margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        }

    ul li{
     float: left;
        width: 200px;
       height: 40px;
       background-color: black;
     opacity: .8;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-right: 100px;
         }

    ul li a{
          text-decoration: none;
           color: white;
       display: block;
                 }

       ul li a:hover{
     color: green;
            }

     ul li ul li{
     display: none;
     }

     ul li:hover ul li{
    display: block;
    }
  
       .obsah-top {
       background: url(cont-top.png) no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #000000;
      }
  
      .stred-obrazok {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      margin: 0;
      top: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      margin-right: -50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
  
      .uvodny-text {
      font-family: Calibri;
          font-size: 40px;
      color: #008000;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 15%;
      }
  


     .pozadie {
     position: absolute;
     width: 70%;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("pozadie2.png") repeat scroll 0 0;
     height: auto;
     box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #000000;
     margin-left: 16%;
     margin-top: 7%;
     z-index: -50;
   
          }

     h1 {
      text-align: center;
     font-family: Helvetica;
     font-size: 35px;
    color: #008000;
     margin-top: 9%;
     }
 
     *{
      margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style: none;
            text-decoration: none;
    }

    .slider{
     overflow: hidden;
     height: 350px;
      margin-top: 3%;
      margin-right: 5%;
      margin-left: 5%;
     }

    .slider figure div{
     width: 20%;
     float: left;
      }

      .slider figure img{
      width: 100%;
       float: left;
      }

      .slider figure{
       position: relative;
       width: 500%;
       margin: 0;
       left: 0;
       animation: 30s slidy infinite;
      }

       @keyframes slidy{
 0%{
  left: 0%
 }

 10%{
  left: 0%;
 }

 12%{
  left: -100%;
 }

 22%{
  left: -100%;
 }

 24%{
  left: -200%;
 }

 34%{
  left: -200%;
 }

 36%{
  left: -300%;
 }

 46%{
  left: -300%;
 }

 48%{
  left: -400%;
 }

 58%{
  left: -400%;
 }

 60%{
  left: -300%;
 }

 70%{
  left: -300%;
 }

 72%{
  left: -200%;
 }

 82%{
  left: -200%;
 }

 84%{
  left: -100%;
 }

 94%{
  left: -100%;
 }

 96%{
  left: 0%;
 }

 100%{
  left: 0%;
 }
    }

     .box-1 {
       width: 45%;
        height: auto;
        background: #DF7401;
        box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #DF7401;
        margin-left: 2%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 6%;
     }

    .obrazokvboxe {
        width: 50%;
        height: auto;
       float: left;
       margin-left: 5%;
           margin-top: 5%;
           margin-bottom: 2%;
       }

       .box-2 {
           width: 45%;
           height: auto;
           background: #DF7401;
           box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #DF7401;
           margin-right: 2%;
           float: right;
           margin-top: 6%;
       }

       p {
           margin-left: 3%;
           font-family: Calibri;
           font-size: 23px;
           color: #FFFFFF;
           margin-right: 3%;
           position: relative;
       }

       .textvboxe {
           margin-left: 0%;
           font-family: Helvetica;
           font-size: 15px;
           color: #008000;
           margin-right: 3%;
           margin-top: 23%; 
       }

       h2 {
           text-align: center;
           font-family: Helvetica;
           font-size: 25px;
           color: #FFFFFF;
           margin-top: 9%;    
       }

       .button {
           background-color: #4CAF50;
           border: none;
           color: white;
           padding: 15px 32px;
          text-align: center;
           text-decoration: none;
           display: inline-block;
           font-size: 16px;
          cursor: pointer;
           margin-left: 5%;
           margin-bottom: 3%;
           margin-top: 5%;
           box-shadow: 0 0 6px 2px #6E6E6E;
       }

       .logo1 {
           background-color: #FFFFFF;
           float: left;
           margin-left: 0;
           margin-top: 0;
           width: auto;
           height: auto;
              }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
     <html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
       <title>Domov - TILIA Naturálna medicína</title>
        <style type="text/css"> 
<body>
         <ul>                       
             <li><a><a href="domov.html">Domov</a></a>                    
             </li>                       
             <li><a><a href="o-nas.html">O nás</a></a>                    
             <ul>                           
               <li><a>Domov</a>                        
               </li>                           
               <li><a>O nás</a>                        
               </li>                           
               <li><a>Produkty</a>                        
               </li>                           
               <li><a>Blog</a>                        
               </li>                           
               <li><a>Kontakt</a>                        
               </li>                     
             </ul>                    
             </li>                       
             <li><a>Produkty</a>                    
             <ul>                  
               <li><a>Domov</a>               
               </li>                  
               <li><a>O nás</a>               
               </li>                  
               <li><a>Produkty</a>               
               </li>                  
               <li><a>Blog</a>               
               </li>                  
               <li><a>Kontakt</a>               
                      </li>              
             </ul>             
             </li>                       
             <li><a>Blog</a>                    
             <ul>         
               <li><a>Domov</a>      
               </li>         
               <li><a>O nás</a>      
               </li>         
               <li><a>Produkty</a>      
               </li>         
               <li><a>Blog</a>      
               </li>         
               <li><a>Kontakt</a>      
               </li>       
             </ul>      
             </li>                       
             <li><a>Kontakt</a>                    
             </li>                 
           </ul>
    
         <div class="pozadie">
           <h1>Vitajte na našej stránke!</h1>
     <div class="slider">
  <figure>
   <div class="slide">
    <img src="images/slide_one.jpg">
   </div>

   <div class="slide">
    <img src="images/slide_two.jpg">
   </div>

   <div class="slide">
    <img src="images/slide_three.jpg">
   </div>

   <div class="slide">
    <img src="images/slide_four.jpg">
   </div>

   <div class="slide">
    <img src="images/slide_five.jpg">
   </div>
  </figure>
 </div>
    <div class="box-1">
         <div class="obrazokvboxe"><img src="chudnutie.png"></div>
         <h2>Chudnutie</h2>
         <div class="textvboxe">
                   <p>
                      Volam sa Dagmara Oremusova, narodila som sa v auguste 1970, pochadzam zo Zvolena, 15 rokov som žila mimo našej krajiny, 10 rokov  v Mexicu. Tam som sa stretla s alternatívnou medicínou a iným pohľadom na zdravie a krásu tela. 
                   </p>
            </div>
           <a href="zdravie.html" class="button">Čítať ďalej...</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="box-2">
            <div class="obrazokvboxe"><img src="zdravie.png"></div>
            <h2>Zdravá výživa</h2>
            <div class="textvboxe">
                   <p>
                      Volam sa Dagmara Oremusova, narodila som sa v auguste 1970, pochadzam zo Zvolena, 15 rokov som žila mimo našej krajiny, 10 rokov  v Mexicu. Tam som sa stretla s alternatívnou medicínou a iným pohľadom na zdravie a krásu tela. 
                   </p>
            </div>
            <a href="zdravie.html" class="button">Čítať ďalej...</a>
           </div>
    
         </div>  
         </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are talking about the images, just add `img {max-width:100%}` but in general to make your page works well when you zoom, you should use `media query` to target your screen width and apply custom css for the screen.